# Constrained UIButton frame is not updating to the buttons constrained position in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I have the following class that creates a UIButton subclass. I have set this up so the button automatically constrains itself to the superview and sets it's height.

```
@IBDesignable
class PrimaryButtonConstrained: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8 {
        didSet {
            setupPrimaryConstrainedButton()
        }
    }
       
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setupPrimaryConstrainedButton()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var topConstraint: CGFloat = 100 {
        didSet {
            layoutSubviews()
        }
    }
       
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupPrimaryConstrainedButton()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupPrimaryConstrainedButton()
    }
       
    override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.topAnchor, constant: topConstraint).isActive = true
        
    }
    
    func setupPrimaryConstrainedButton() {
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.gray, for: .disabled)
        setTitleColor(.orange, for: .highlighted)
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        if isEnabled {
            backgroundColor = .orange
        } else {
            backgroundColor = .gray
        }
        
    }
    
       override public func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
            super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
            setupPrimaryConstrainedButton()
       }

}
```

The button constraints itself correctly in interface builder when you set the button class, however the frame of the button does not update to the buttons new location as shown.

[image: broken_button]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix the frame so it still encloses the button?

Comment: what this constraint do ? `topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.topAnchor, constant: topConstraint).isActive = true` ?

Comment: it sets the top anchor constraint to to top of the superview. The value is initially 100 and can be modified in interface builder.

Comment: What is the marked area (with small squares) below the button ? Is it the expected button frame ? Where in code do you set it ? Or do you do it in IB, with which values ?

Comment: great question! The marked area is actually the frame of the button. That is where I initially dropped the button in interface builder. After you apply the button class the button moves to the correct location shown in the image but the frame stays were it was dropped.

Comment: It's easy to test this locally, all you need to do it copy the class into a swift file and apply the class in interface builder to a button and you should get the same result.

Comment: @SM654321 - I think you'll find that trying to add "internal constraints relative to superview" will **not** work as desired in Storyboard / Interface Builder. It just doesn't.

Comment: @DonMag Not sure I understand as the button applies the constraints in Interface Builder and when I run the app the button is in the correct location. It's just the selection frame with the little handles on it that is in the wrong place. Might be a bug in Xcode?

Comment: @SM654321 - sorry, yeah, I meant it won't work ***properly*** in IB. It may *look* correct, but IB won't fully understand where it is. So, as you've seen, the selection handles will be misplaced... you can't select it in IB where you *see* it (you have to select it in document outline or select it where the "misplaced handles" are)... constraining other UI elements relative to it can get tricky as well. Also, be ***very careful*** trying to assign constraints in `layoutSubviews()` as that can be called multiple times.

Comment: @DonMag many thanks! This clears things up, and thanks for the alert on using layoutSubviews()